# Updating many to many relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, dbcontext, ef-database-first

I'm able to create a user successfully. I'm now trying to assign some roles to the user during the creation process.

I'm using a database-first approach with Entity Framework. I've tried following some tutorials and looking at other peoples solutions, but can't seem to get it working.

I have 3 tables: `User`, `Role`, and `UserRole` (contains `UserId` and `RoleId`).

The relationship between `User` and `Role` is many-to-many.

[Entity Diagram Showing Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaidO.png)

[The Create view, which contains checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYt7N.png)

Database context class:

```
public partial class MyDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyDBEntities() : base("name=MyDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs:**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password_hash { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**Role.cs:**

```
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**[HttpGet] Create():**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
        return View(new UserCreateVM
        {
            Roles = db.Roles.Select(x => new RoleCheckboxVM
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                IsChecked = false
            }).ToList()
        });
    }
```

**[HttpPost] Create():**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserCreateVM vm)
{
        User user = new User();

        var selectedRoles = new List<Role>();

        foreach (var r in db.Roles)   // we query all the roles in the database
        {
            var checkbox = vm.Roles.Single(x => x.Id == r.Id);
            checkbox.Name = r.Name; //updates the name on all our checkboxes

            if (checkbox.IsChecked) //if checkbox is checked
            {
                selectedRoles.Add(r); //then we add the role to our selectedRoles
            }
        }

        IList<Role> rolesList = user.Roles.ToList();

        foreach (var toAdd in selectedRoles.Where(x => !rolesList.Contains(x))) //if roles is not already added
        {
            rolesList.Add(toAdd); //then we add them to the user roles
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //We update the data on the object
            user.Username = vm.Username;
            user.Email = vm.Email;

            user.SetPassword(vm.Password_hash); //we hash the password

            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried adding **db.Roles.AddRange(rolesList);** but that just inserts the selected roles inside the Role table. Still struggling with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve this.

1. The Many-to-Many table UserRole didn't have any primary key. Therefore I added a PK consistent of both the UserId and the RoleId.
2. I removed the rolesList as I didn't need it

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create(UserCreateVM vm)

   {

      User user = new User();

      var selectedRoles = new List<Role>();

      foreach (var r in db.Roles)   // we query all the roles in the database
      {
          var checkbox = vm.Roles.Single(x => x.Id == r.Id);
          checkbox.Name = r.Name; //updates the name on all our checkboxes

          if (checkbox.IsChecked) //if checkbox is checked
          {
              selectedRoles.Add(r); //then we add the role to our selectedRoles
          }
      }

      foreach (var r in selectedRoles.Where(x => !user.Roles.Contains(x))) //if roles is not already added
      {
          user.Roles.Add(r); //then we add them to the user roles
      }

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          //We update the data on the object
          user.Username = vm.Username;
          user.Email = vm.Email;

          user.SetPassword(vm.Password_hash); //we hash the password

          db.Users.Add(user);
          db.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      return View(vm);
   }
   ```

Then after updating both the database table and the database model (edmx) everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see when did you assign the roles to user.roles, as I can see, you are assigning user.roles to rolesList  instead of assigning rolesList to user.roles. 
This is how I would do it.

```
    User user = new User()
    {

     Roles = db.Roles.Where(r => vm.Roles.Any(x => x.IsChecked && r.Id = x.Id)).ToList(),
     Username = vm.Username,
     Email = vm.Email
     };

        user.SetPassword(vm.Password_hash); //we hash the password

        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This results in the following error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyWebApp.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.RoleCheckboxVM>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyWebApp.Models.Role>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I updated the answer, my bad I didn't notice that it is not the same type.